# Solution/Project name variable in TFS Build 2010

Tags: version-control, build, build-automation

When creating a new build definition in TFS 2010 we specifiy a project or solution to build (Under the 'Required -> Items to Build' section in the 'Process' section of the definition.

Is there any way to get hold of the name of the solution being built in the Workflow scope? I.e. is the there a variable available with this information inside that I can pass into a custom code activity elsewhere within the work flow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the build workflow and tunnel down into Compile and Test, you'll see a For Each Project  loop scope that shows the workflow variable assignment of BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild as serverBuildProjectItem in an out of the box workflow.  There's a task within the sub-sequence that translates that serverItem to a local path containing the proj file.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be a loop over the files you specified. So if you specified a .sln file, you will not get a loop over the .(cs)proj files contained, but only the one .sln file.

Comment: I would really like to see an updated answer here regarding the VS/TFS2013 templates. They are much more streamlined and these activities you talk about are probably hidden children of the base ones.