# Get project name during TFS Build

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm attempting to deploy a web application using TFS Build 2010.  The files I need to deploy are located in {DropFolder}_PublishedWebsites\HelloWorld.  I have added a copy directory activity, and can point it to the {DropFolder}_PublishedWebsites" directory, but I am not finding a way to extract the name of the project currently being built to append it to the path.

This should be easy.  What am I missing?  I'd expect to find this somewhere in the object model, but I cannot locate it.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572567/solution-project-name-variable-in-tfs-build-2010 help?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not as easy as one would have thought. We have implemented this through an argument that defines the a project directory name, and this is then used to define paths such as the one you want. Not very pretty, but the simpler way for us since we often build more than one solution in our builds and need to tell the build which one of those is the "main" project.

I suppose it should be possible to parse from the solution(s) being built, using `Path` methods as well.